# Excel Pivot Table add % column

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a Pivot:

```
City           HC    TC
--------------------------------
London         50    100
Manchester     67    250
Leeds          20    20
```

All I need to do is, within the Pivot table, add another column that calculates the percentage based on the second and third columns.

The outcome would be:

```
City           HC    TC
--------------------------------
London         50    100    50%
Manchester     67    250    27%
Leeds          20    20     100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `Fields, Items & Sets` click `Calculated Field...` and add your formula that's dependent on other columns in the Pivot table.

---

### Example:

The database:

[image]

The Pivot table (with `Field2` formula: `= Revenue / Units`):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks and yep, that's the most logical approach - yet I'm getting `#DIV/0!` - both columns of Data are text, does that makes a difference?